# Install a SQL CLR user defined function

Tags: sql-server-2005, clr, sqlclr

I'm testing out some SQL CLR stuff in VS 2008 and SQL Server 2005, how do I install a user defined function on the database? I built it and have the DLL, but now what?

Comment: You would use `CREATE ASSEMBLY`. One of the first Google hits: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254956(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: oh okay so create assembly is for that too, thanks!

Comment: And then `CREATE FUNCTION ... EXTERNAL NAME` (that example uses a procedure but the syntax is the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use [`CREATE ASSEMBLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254956%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). e.g.:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY MyAssembly FROM 'C:\path\fille.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;
GO
```

And then optional syntax for `CREATE FUNCTION` that references the function in your assembly (the external name will be dependent on how you structured your code):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction(@param <data_type>)
RETURNS <data_type>
AS EXTERNAL NAME MyAssembly.SqlServerFunctions.FunctionName;
```